# Do large amount of scenes cause performance issues in unity?

Tags: performance, unity-game-engine, 2d-games, levels

I am making a pixel art puzzle platformer game in unity.

I had the idea to make 4 chapters with 50 levels each and some bonus levels for paid version, so about 250 levels.

Now as i never worked with large amount of levels i had no idea if i could put each level in a seperate scene or if it would cause performance issues. Each level would contain only 36x36 pixel art sprites and some enemy type of things, not more.

If it is a bad idea to have each level in a seperate scene, which method would be better to avoid performance issues and too high memory usage when implementing 250+ levels.

Comment: Well. If the scenes work the same way it might be better to have some form of generation process but generally as only one scene is active maybe a couple but not all it shouldn't be that bad but the size of your distribution maybe big

Answer (score 0):

In short - no, it doesn't.

However, it strongly depends on how will you manage your assets, not on the number of scenes in your project.

If you will not use scenes to load additively, all should be fine. All resources related to the old scene should be unloaded during the loading of the new scene (btw, there is even an old hack to prevent memory spikes during loading one memory-heavy scene from another memory-heavy scene - loading an almost empty scene to ensure that not needed assets are unloaded before the loading of the new heavy scene will begin).

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer! Just to be sure, the assets only change every chapter, so 50 levels use the same assets and the next 50 use different assets. The only thing that changes in the same chapter is the structure of the levels. So again, do you think i can create 250 scenes in my unity project without worrieng about abnormal memory usage or performance issues? Do other developers also create so many scenes in their games when having many different levels?

Comment: This is game dev =) There are no ideal practices that fit every single project =) Some of the solutions that saved one project can easily be critically bad for another project =) I don't know why you want to create separate scenes. Maybe, it is really needed in your case. But it is definitely not better or worse than other variants in terms of performance.

Comment: As for me, I will make a single scene with many "level" prefabs or even some level descriptions in binary format in a common case. But mostly in terms of my personal convenience and possible future resource management.